# Paypal express checkout error in magento (Redirect to cart page)

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I am finding it difficult to checkout with "Pay pal express checkout" option on a Magento store on which i am working currently

When have tried debug and checked the payment_paypal_express.log file and i found this error log

```
2013-11-23T14:44:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [url] => https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
    [SetExpressCheckout] => Array
        (
            [PAYMENTACTION] => Order
            [AMT] => 899.98
            [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
            [RETURNURL] => http://alpha.coverking.com/paypal/express/return/
            [CANCELURL] => http://alpha.coverking.com/paypal/express/cancel/
            [INVNUM] => 100000593
            [SOLUTIONTYPE] => Mark
            [GIROPAYCANCELURL] => http://alpha.coverking.com/paypal/express/cancel/
            [GIROPAYSUCCESSURL] => http://alpha.coverking.com/checkout/onepage/success/
            [BANKTXNPENDINGURL] => http://alpha.coverking.com/checkout/onepage/success/
            [LOCALECODE] => en_US
            [ITEMAMT] => 899.98
            [TAXAMT] => 0.00
            [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
            [L_NUMBER0] => CVC3SP297
            [L_NAME0] => Stormproof Class 3
            [L_QTY0] => 1
            [L_AMT0] => 449.99
            [L_NUMBER1] => CVC3SP298
            [L_NAME1] => Stormproof Class 3
            [L_QTY1] => 1
            [L_AMT1] => 449.99
            [BUSINESS] => 
            [NOTETEXT] => 
            [EMAIL] => abhi@gmail.com
            [FIRSTNAME] => Abhi
            [LASTNAME] => Sharma
            [MIDDLENAME] => 
            [SALUTATION] => 
            [SUFFIX] => 
            [COUNTRYCODE] => US
            [STATE] => WA
            [CITY] => Washington
            [STREET] => USEPA Ariel Rios Building (AR) 1200 Pennsylvania Avenue N.W. Washington, DC 20004
            [ZIP] => 20004
            [PHONENUM] => 206-512-9668
            [SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => US
            [SHIPTOSTATE] => WA
            [SHIPTOCITY] => Washington
            [SHIPTOSTREET] => USEPA Ariel Rios Building (AR) 1200 Pennsylvania Avenue N.W. Washington, DC 20004
            [SHIPTOZIP] => 20004
            [SHIPTOPHONENUM] => 206-512-9668
            [SHIPTOSTREET2] => 
            [STREET2] => 
            [SHIPTONAME] => Abhi Sharma
            [ADDROVERRIDE] => 1
            [METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [USER] => ****
            [PWD] => ****
            [SIGNATURE] => ****
            [BUTTONSOURCE] => Varien_Cart_EC_US
        )

    [response] => Array
        (
            [TIMESTAMP] => 2013-11-23T14:44:24Z
            [CORRELATIONID] => 781548ab77ed8
            [ACK] => Failure
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [BUILD] => 8549850
            [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10736
            [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Shipping Address Invalid City State Postal Code
            [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => A match of the Shipping Address City, State, and Postal Code failed.
            [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
        )

    [__pid] => 13299
)
```

As i can see in error description is it saying that "Shipping Address Invalid City State Postal Code" but i am giving real address, city, state, postal code.

Although the express checkout is working fine on cart page. Its giving error only when we go to the checkout page and use paypal express checkout from there.

Note: I have disabled other payment methods and there is no entry in exception and system log files.

Comment: In which country you are providing the shipping? I thisnk billing and shipping address must match.